# What causes train loss to suddenly rise, and never fall back, starting at some epoch?

Tags: deep-learning

Please see the following train/val losses of some basic vision binary classifier training I am performing.

[image]

I thought train loss should always go down.
When dropping the learning rate, this still happens, but at a latter epoch.
I also recall this happening on entirely different data and architecture a while back, but I couldn't explain it back then as well.

This isn't overfitting, as both train and val loss drop together up to some epoch ("iteration" in the graphs), and then BOTH suddenly rise, not only val loss.

1. Does this observed phenomenon have a name?
2. What could cause it?
3. Is there a standard solution?
4. How to debug?

Comment: Is always at iteration (epoch) 100? Have you checked your dataset if label is good? Also if you share loss functions (it looks like train and validation loss function differ), it will help us to guess.

Comment: learning rate schedule, exploding gradient, ill-formation of the optimization

Comment: Your validation loss appears to be three orders of magnitude greater than training loss. Is that correct on the graph?